# escape square brackets with formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm using Formik in react and I'm having issues with square brackets when using the validation in order to show errors on screen. I tried with `"\["` but it didn't work. Insted using something like "text" or "text-i" or even "text(i)" works fine, but I'm having problems only with square brackets.

```
isDataValid = (values: KeyValue<any>) => {
        let errors: FormikErrors<KeyValue<any>> = {};

      (for let i=0; i<... etc) {
        if (!values["text[i]"]) {
            errors["text[i]"] = "Insert title";
        }
     }  

        return errors;
```

Any tips?

Comment: Can you provide more context?

Answer (score 0):

Not utilising `i` seems to be the issue. In-order to use `i` within `for` loop in this case, you can make use of template literals, or `+`.

Using template literals :

```
(for let i=0; i<... etc) {
    if (!values[`text[${i}]`]) {
        errors[`text[${i}]`] = "Insert title";
    }
 }
```

Using `+`:

```
(for let i=0; i<... etc) {
    if (!values["text[" + i + "]"]) {
        errors["text[" + i + "]"] = "Insert title";
    }
 }
```

Please note the use of template literals may result compatibility issues, refer: https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals